# How to configure ipv4 Link-Local on Linux with systemd-networkd without violating RFC3927 specifications?

Tags: systemd, dhcp, systemd-networkd, avahi, mdns

I'm using an embedded device with Linux 4.9 and systemd.
I configured systemd-networkd in this way:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=v4

[DHCPv4]
UseHostname=false
```

How can I setup Link-Local only when my device doesn't receive an IP address?

I know that I can use something like mdns, avahi and so on, but I'm trying to talk about this topic in a general way, to understand the logic and all possible alternatives.

PS: If required, I can replace also systemd-networkd with something else. I'm searching for the best option RFC3927-compliant.

Comment: Is it actually necessary for the interface to **not** have a Link-Local IPv4 address when it receives another address? Or in other words, have you tried just enabling the Link-Local address setup always, regardless of whether or not the DHCP will be successful?

Comment: Yes I tried to enable LinkLocal and it's working, however I have to pass a certification procedure and requirements say that I need a Link Local address only after some second of delay (60000 ms). Also, RFC3927 specify behaviour about conflicts and so on.